# Understanding the difference between second and moment

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Below are the two sentences. Which one should be used and when?

> The Earth is protected every second.
>
> The Earth is protected every moment.

Comment: Although *second* and *moment* are practically synonyms, "every" and "all" are not.  The phrase "every second" does not mean "at all times". *Every second* refers to a frequency.

Comment: @TRomano, is moment countable ?? I know second has life span of one second, but what is the life span of moment ?

Comment: The lifespan of a moment, although it may be indefinite, is a span  nonetheless.

Comment: @TRomano that is what i am telling how both are same then ??

Comment: I don't understand your last remark.  But the two words are synonymous insofar as they refer to a span of time and an instant of time.  Consider: may I have a half of your sandwich? May I have a piece of your sandwich?  "Piece" is not exact like "half".   "Moment" is not exact like "second".

Comment: If a light comes on "every second" it flashes with each tick of a clock's second-hand.  If a light comes on "every few moments", it flashes, but we don't know the exact frequency. So yes, **moment** can be countable.

Comment: @TRomano not clear still, but at least know that they both are synonymous with each other.

Comment: **Moment** can refer to a span of time. "I will be there in a moment." Or it can refer to an instant of time.  "Do you have a car?  No, not at the moment."   Do you understand the difference between **span** and **instant**?

Comment: @TRomano yup that's clear to me.

Comment: "At the moment" means "now".   But we never say "At the second" to mean "now".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pedantic answer is that a [*second*](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/second.html) is an SI unit of time with a precisely defined duration and that a [*moment*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+moment&oq=define+moment) is just a short period of time of arbitrary duration.

In common usage though, the two terms are effectively synonymous.  In your example sentences both will be readily understood as meaning that the Earth is continuously protected.

Whether you use *second* or *moment* in writing such as this is a matter of style and preference.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the unusual fact that "one second" does not always equal 1 second. When a clerk says, "I'll be with you in one second," that doesn't mean "in 1/60th of a minute. It means, well, "in a few moments."

Comment: If we're being pedantic: [in medieval times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(time)), a moment was a measure of time, on average about 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A *moment* is an ambiguous unit of time, it could be anywhere between a few milliseconds and 3 seconds (not necessarily limited to 3 seconds).

A *second* is a precise unit of time, precisely equal to 9,192,631,770 cycles of the radiation that gets an atom of the element called cesium to vibrate between two energy states<sup>[1](http://www.livescience.com/32660-how-does-an-atomic-clock-work.html)</sup>.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant "3 seconds" literally. As you say, a moment is an ambiguous amount of time, it could easily be more than 3 seconds. I'm not sure what the absolute upper bound would be.

Comment: @Jay I think the upper bound even goes up the further a moment is in the past. We can think of the big bang as a moment without much trouble, even though the entire event took billions of years.

Comment: That bit about the cesium atom is interesting, and even a little funny, but, for the sake of completeness, you really should mention that a second is [also](https://www.wordnik.com/words/second) an imprecise unit of time, roughly synonymous with _moment._

Comment: @J.R. As with most things in the English language, we're both correct and it depends entirely on context. I'm sure a second would be a precise measure of time in certain fields, see [Atomic Clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock), But I could also say "I'll be 1 second" which could mean a couple of minutes.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't mean to say that a second was _never_ used as a precise measure. It is – in science, and in sports. No commentator would ever say, "There are 3.6 moments left in this basketball game."